# Moq; Unit Test - Method is always failing. ISetup is not working

Tags: unit-testing, moq, c#-3.0, controller-tests

The test method is always failing. After the `Setup` the method `UpdateAsync` should return 1 in the result but it remains always 0 which results in exception in the controller method.

Can you tell what I am missing here ?

```
[Test]
public async Task UpdateImportHeaderAsyncTest()
{
    //Arrange
    HeaderRequest request = new HeaderRequest()
    {
        ConfigurationId = 1,
        Key = "1",
        Status = 1
    };
    _manager.Setup(a => a.UpdateAsync(_mockData.Header)).Returns(Task.FromResult(1));

    //Act
    var actual = await Controller.UpdateHeaderAsync(request);

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(actual);
}
```

```
//Controller Method
[HttpPut]
public async Task<int> UpdateHeaderAsync(HeaderRequest request)
{
    var result = 0;
    try
    {
        result = await _manager.UpdateAsync(new Header() 
        { 
          HeaderId = request.Id, 
          Status = request.Status, 
          ConfigurationId = request.ConfigurationId 
        });

        if (result == 0)
        {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException("No records found.", "1", "");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {      
        throw;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: have u ever mocked HTTPContext.Current.request ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loosen the argument match  using `It.IsAny<Header>()`to get the desired behavior.

```
//...

_manager
    .Setup(a => a.UpdateAsync(It.IsAny<Header>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(1);

//...
```

The setup also allows for `ReturnsAsync` for setting up async members.

What was happening before was that you were setting it up with a specific referenced instance. That instance was not the same one used when exercising the test since you initialized a `new Header`. This caused the mock to return the default value for the return type.

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the framework